# Xdebug doesn't show up as a module

Tags: xdebug

System:

> OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
> Version   10.0.19041 Build 19041

dll location and version:

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

php.ini info:

> C:\xampp\php\php.ini
> [XDebug]
> zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

`phpinfo()`:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

`php -v` output:

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 17:29:57) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )  
Copyright (c) The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

When I run `php -m`, the output is

> [PHP Modules]
> (a bunch of modules, but no xdebug)
> [Zend Modules]
> (empty)

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

I would bet your `php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll` is just not compatible with your PHP.
Double check if you don't see anywhere something like
`Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll`
Also check if your edited `php.ini` is really used by your php binary.

In my Windows box I have `zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll` in `php.ini` and `PHP 7.4.10 (cli)` `( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )` and it works like charm.
**Check NTS vs ZTS**. Maybe you should use `php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll`

Comment: There are no error messages that I can see. The `php.ini` in my question appears as the "Loaded Configuration File" in `phpinfo()`. I switched to the NTS version of the dll, but it made no difference.